# The difference between A none clustered primary-key and a covering index in terms of performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, covering-index

I have a table which contains a nonclustered primary-key. I intend to remove this primary-key and create a unique Covering Index on the same column instead.

Then The table won't have a primary-key, but a unique covering index.

I searched google but could not find a relevant topic. Is that fundamentally wrong? or it's ok to be done.

**Update:**

Why do I need to convert this index to a covering index?

Because this is the primary-key and I have many select queries based on this key. At the moment for each select, there will be a need for a RID Lookup because this is a NONE clustered key. If I convert it to a covering index, this RID Lookup will be gone for those select queries and hopefully there will be better performance (at least the excecution plan says that).

Of course integrity is also intended and that's why I will make it a unique covering index. The primary-key is uniqueidentifier.

What I am wondering is if that has any negative effects on anything else.

**Execution Plan Before:**

[image]

**Execution Plan After:**

[image]

Comment: @WEI_DBA Foreign keys can reference Alternate Keys as well as Primary Keys.

Comment: The term "covering" always is referenced to some query. Your question has no query, so what do you mean saying "covering index"? Clustered index?

Comment: You're really mixing up a lot of terms here. What is the purpose of what you are doing? Performance or data integrity? What reason do you have for _not_ making your unique index the primary key? Are the columns different between the two objects?

Comment: @sepupic I updated the question. Please read it again.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  I updated the question. Please read it again.

Comment: Do you have NULLs in the columns you want to use as unique index? If no, what is the problem with a clustered PK, especially if you use that key to look up values in the table (I am not referring to the lookup operation). If there are NULLs possible, what is wrong with a clustered UNIQUE? Do you plan to reference these columns in foreign keys?

Comment: @Pred the problem is that the primary-key values are generated in the code (and we can't change it) and then saved in the db. Due to the nature of the cluster indexes, they are sorted physically on the disk. Having the key as a unique identifier, slows it down while inserting recoreds to the table. We have observed it in the past.

Comment: Non-clustered unique index with the `INCLUDE` clause acts as a clustered index for that particular subset of data and 'sorted' 'physically' on the disk too. Your performance gain most probably is due to the limited data stored in the index. Valid reason, just an explanation without knowing your actual data and structure.

Comment: So the current primary key is a app generated GUID which is of no value in searching and has no actual meaning except that it's unique. (thanks programmers >:| ). I suggest you simply make this primary key a unique constraint or index instead, (to basically document it's uniqueness), then pick a _useful_ primary key that is narrow and whose leading column is frequently searched on.

Comment: With regards to negative effects: Keep in mind that some ORM's require primary keys to be set up so they can automatically identify the update / insert key. You need to test it in a non production environment and make sure your developers regenerate their ORM model successfully. Then send them on a database training course!

Answer (score 1):

It's fundamentally unusual, but there could be some rare situation where it's fine.

You haven't told us anything about the reason for wanting to do this, so we can't really offer more than that.

EDIT:

According to [this article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/foreign-keys-can-reference-unique-indexes-without-constraints/) by Kimberly Tripp, Foreign Keys can reference the columns of a UNIQUE INDEX that INCLUDE columns to cover queries.

To me, this means that it is probably fine to replace your Primary Key with a Unique Covering Index.  The only negative implication of this I can think of is that any application or query that looks at the meta data of your table to find the Primary Key will not find one, and may not be smart enough to use the Alternate Key instead.  For example, if you ever built a cube on this table, the Data Source View wizard might not automatically create the relationship.

Comment: I updated the question and explained the desired goal. Please read it again and let me know if you have any more questions.